# Is a margin in css a proper way to clear space under an image?

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

Hey @all I have an image on the left side and a text on the right side of a container. 
My goal is to have the image stay on the left without anything appearing under it. This could be done with bootstrap obviously but with pure CSS, is a margin underneath the img a proper way to keep the text on the right side? The problem is that the margin has to be adjusted to the length of the paragraph. What would be a better way to do this?

HTML

```
  <div class="container test">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels- 
             photo.jpg?cs=srgb&dl=abandoned-forest-hd-wallpaper-34950.jpg&fm=jpg"
             alt="">
        <h3>hola</h3>
        <p>I am a long paragraph, a very long one Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
            nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam.</p>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.test {
      width: 300px;

      img {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 10rem;
      }
    }
```

Here is what it looks like: 
[Screenshot with margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjdJY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the text content in it's own div and float *that*.

```css
.test {
  width: 300px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container test">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="">
  <div class="wrap">
    <h3>hola</h3>
    <p>I am a long paragraph, a very long one Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a container around the text elements and a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) for `.test` The default setting for each flexbox item is [stretch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items), which means it will have its own space from top to bottom and will be as tall as the tallest item in the flexbox.

```css
.test {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container test">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="">
  <!-- Container added for text elements -->
  <div class="text-container">
    <h3>hola</h3>
    <p>I am a long paragraph, a very long one Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```